# ERROR "'Provider type not defined' when tried to generated CSR in MMC Console

Tags: console, certificate, ssl-certificate, csr, mmc

My question, why when i'm trying to generate CSR in MMC Console, the pop up "provided type not defined" error will appeared? the error code -0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF). You may refer picture

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days, luckily I got the answer for my question. If you want to generate CSR with CNG key, make sure the **'CNG Key Isolation' service is running.** If not, error 'provider not defined' will appear.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen if you dont have a TPM chip on your computer and you set the Provider Name to "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider".